# HTTP Options enabled on non-servers

Tags: http, http-options-method

I recently scanned a list of nodes and noticed that HTTP Options Method is enabled on several devices that are not web servers, or servers at all (for example, printers, Win10 nodes, etc.)

My first guess is that it's because these devices can be managed via a web interface, although that still wouldn't explain the Win10 devices.
Can anyone provide some insight into why this vulnerability would be appearing on these devices?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What makes you think this is a vulnerability? In any case it doesn’t seem to relate to programming so it might be better at Super User or other sister site

Comment: It's more of a best practice, but the vulnerability scanner I'm using is classifying it as a vulnerability. So, I have to remediate it due to company policy. But yes, I agree. I'll ask the folks on Spiceworks or Super User.